# Try render components in a Root component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this problem for week now and just can't find solutions.
I try to render the components in the Root component.

**index.js file:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link,
} from 'react-router'

import IndexContent from './components/indexContent';
import IndexHome from './components/indexHome';
import Root from './components/root';


class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Router>
        <Root>
          <Route exact path="/" component={IndexContent}/>
          <Route path="/indexhome" component={IndexHome} />
        </Root>
       </Router>
      )
  }
}

export default App;

ReactDOM.render( <App/>, document.getElementById('wrapper'));
```

**root.js file:**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

import NavBar from './NavBar';
import Footer from './footer';

class Root extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
                <div>
                    <NavBar/>
                    {this.props.children}
                    <Footer/>
                </div>
        )
    }
};


export default Root;
```

**indexContent.js file:**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';


class IndexContent extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
                <h1>IndexContent</h1>
            )
    }
};



export default IndexContent;
```

**indexHome.js file:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';


class IndexHome extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <h1>IndexHome</h1>
        )
    }
}

export default IndexHome;
```

and the error that I am getting is:

1) **Warning:** **React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `App`.**

2) **Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `App`.
    at invariant (bundle.js:946)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.instantiateReactComponent [as _instantiateReactComponent] (bundle.js:12837)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (bundle.js:22340)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js:22231)
    at Object.mountComponent (bundle.js:4663)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (bundle.js:22344)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js:22231)
    at Object.mountComponent (bundle.js:4663)
    at mountComponentIntoNode (bundle.js:12047)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (bundle.js:7037)**

Comment: Can you share us indexContent.js and indexHome.js code? There should be something wrong. Or it could be your imports. Anyways, code would give us more decent understanding

Comment: @GiorgiKhorguani 
Thank you for the answer. I just edit so you can see the indexContent.js and indexHome.js
Also, I am using react-router v4 (if it makes any different)

Comment: I think that one of the `import` statements is invalid. Try to 1. verify all paths are correct. 2. add the `.js` extension to them, e.g. `import Root from './components/root.js';

Comment: @msbir Why are you using <Root> component? Is this just a wrapper? Can you try to wrap <Router> by <Root>.

`<Root>
        <Router>
          <Route exact path="/" component={IndexContent}/>
          <Route path="/indexhome" component={IndexHome} />
        </Router>
       </Root>`

Comment: @GiorgiKhorguani
The <Root> component is for getting the children to be dynamically display so in every page the <NavBar/> and <footer/> components will stay. 
You can see it in the Root.js file

I try do what you suggest, still not working

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement class for `App` element. Just wrap it into the arrow function and pass in the `ReactDom.render`

```
const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <Root>
           <Route exact path="/" component={IndexContent}/>
           <Route path="/indexhome" component={IndexHome} />
        </Root>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render( <App/>, document.getElementById('wrapper'));
```

Comment: actually it would be more easy to figure out the reason when you'l present js code after transpiling step (i guess you use babel). In that case you would see what actually you are sending in the `React.createElement`. In that case would be easy to debug for you the `App` value in runtime.

Comment: `React.createElement` calls in js when you present in the `jsx` dom syntax. Like a '() => (<Element></Element>)` equals to `function(){ return React.createElement(Element, null)}`

Answer (score 0):

I have my app separated out from my routes like so, but can easily be combined:

Routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';

import App from './Components/App';
import Forgot from './Components/Auth/ForgotPassword';
import Register from './Components/Register/RegisterForm';
import NotFound from './Components/NotFound';
import LoginForm from './Components/Auth/LoginForm';
import Logout from './Components/Auth/Logout';
import Admin from './Components/Admin';
import Dashboard from './Components/Dashboard/Dashboard';


const Routes = (props) => (
    <Router {...props}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={LoginForm}/>
            <Route path="register" component={Register}/>
            <Route path="forgotpassword" component={Forgot}/>
            <Route path="logout" component={Logout}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/admin" component={Admin}>
            <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
    </Router>
);

export default Routes;
```

And my main app creator:
index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Routes from './routes';
import './index.css';


ReactDOM.render(
  <Routes history={browserHistory} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: what version of react-router are you using?

Comment: I'm using react-router v3.0.2

Comment: I thought so, I am using v4.0.0
There are some differents between them

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

var reactRouter = require('react-router')
var Router = reactRouter.Router
var Route = reactRouter.Route
var Link = reactRouter.Link
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'
const history = createHashHistory();


import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import IndexContent from './indexContent';
import IndexHome from './indexHome';
import Root from './root';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <Router history={history}>
              <Root>
                <Route exact path='/' component={IndexContent}/>
                <Route path='/indexhome' component={IndexHome} />
              </Root>
          </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And just in case, package.json

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflow",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that! make some sense in this mess.